# Error code SQLCODE: -964

Tags: sql, db2

I am executing a select query. When number of tables is 10 or less then 10 query is executing fine.

```
select * from  SERVEIT.ibasemaster,
SERVEIT.ticket,
SERVEIT.PSEUDOTICKETDETAILS,
SERVEIT.ticketdetails,
SERVEIT.obligationtypemaster,
SERVEIT.STATUSMASTER;
```

but when number of tables increase more than 10 query is not executing and giving error code `"DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.21.29"`. I have searched the issue and get to know this is a space size issue.
I have increased the logproimary size to 8  and logsecond size to 16 but this is also not working.

Comment: SQLCODE -968, as explained in the manual, means that the database file system is full. As mentioned by others, your cross-join of more than 10 tables likely requires enormous amount of temporary space. Consider rewriting your query.

Comment: @mustaccio- You are right.Either I need to change the query or i need to make sure that there is hundreds of gb space in my disc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following query

```
select * from SERVEIT.ibasemaster,
              SERVEIT.ticket,
              SERVEIT.PSEUDOTICKETDETAILS,
              SERVEIT.ticketdetails,
              SERVEIT.obligationtypemaster,
              SERVEIT.STATUSMASTER;
```

you are doing are cross join between the six tables listed, because there is no `ON` clause, nor are there any joining criteria in the `WHERE` clause.  My guess is that when you hit 10 tables the result set becomes so large that it can't fit into memory, or exceeds a memory limit imposed by DB2.

If you really intend to do a cross join, then your only option might be to somehow increase memory.  But a nicer solution would be to add an `ON` clause and restrict the size of your join result set.

Comment: Which memory size should i increase. I have already increased the size of logprimary and logsecond.

Comment: @manoj I'm not expert enough in DB2 to answer this, but you could start by figuring out how many records each of the 10 tables has.  Do you really want a cross product here?

Comment: i have actually created a view of 44 tables with the columns i need, but if i'm not able to run 10 tables, how will i run a script with 44 TABLES, any idea about increasing transaction log?

Answer (score 0):

Possible you have the same column in different tables of your select clause, you must have uniqu name for all column into your select